# AS3 try/catch out of memory

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm loading a few huge images on my flex/as3 app, but I can't manage to catch the error when the flash player runs out of memory.

Here is the what I was thinking might work (I use **????** because i dont know what to catch):

```
try{
    images = new Array(frames);
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < frames; i++){
         imagesBA[i] = new BitmapData(width, height, false, 0x000000FF);
    }
 }
catch(error:????){
     Alert.show("Out of memory!");
}
```

**Any idea what ???? can be?**

**Or does anyone knows how to catch when there is no memory for a variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no catch for it....

Saying that I can always catch all the errror in 10.1 using:

```
if(this.loaderInfo.hasOwnProperty("uncaughtErrorEvents"))
            {
                IEventDispatcher(loaderInfo["uncaughtErrorEvents"]).addEventListener("uncaughtError", global_error_handler);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `flash.errors.MemoryError`. I haven't check if it works, but the asdoc seems to say that's the way to go.

Comment: No, that didn't catch it! :-/