# Air application hangs instead of throwing MemoryError

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, out-of-memory, freeze

### I'm trying to make my application throw `MemoryError` by creating  a very long string, but it hangs instead of throwing it.

I tried this with **air sdk 3.4** and **3.8**, both release and debug builds.
Sometimes when I close the app in a force way, eclipse shows something like `app exited with error code:out of memory`.

I also noticed that console contains line `[Unload SWF] myapp.swf` after executing the code(if you add `trace(str.length)` after doubling the string, you'll see that it happens after length `369098752`).

You can see here [AS3 Reference for MemoryError](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/errors/MemoryError.html) that this is legitimate way of causing `MemoryError`.

**So, how can I really catch those MemoryErrors instead of allowing app to crash?**

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                        creationComplete="onCreation(event)"                        
                       >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;         
            import avmplus.getQualifiedClassName;

            protected var str:String = 'ssssssssssssssssssssss';
            protected function onCreation(event:FlexEvent):void{
                var serverString:String = unescape(Capabilities.serverString);
                try{
                    while(true){
                        str+=str;
                    }
                }catch(e:MemoryError){
                    Alert.show('memoryError');
                }
            }           
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>   
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**update:**
I improved test app, now you can clearly see that no error or uncaught error is thrown.
It crashes when memory usage reaches 1700-1750MB.
I found some bugs that resemble my case in bugbase, but they are related to air 2.x and marked as fixed/not a bug. I can't find any similar bug for air 3.x.

[Bug: App crashes when allocates >1.7GB](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2972487)

[Bug: App crashes when approaches 2GB](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2923050)

**Can anybody reproduce?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                        applicationComplete="onCreation(event)"                     
                       >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.setInterval;

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import avmplus.getQualifiedClassName;

            protected var vectors:Vector.<Vector.<uint>>= new Vector.<Vector.<uint>>();
            protected function onCreation(event:FlexEvent):void{
                loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR,onUncaughtError);
                var serverString:String = unescape(Capabilities.serverString);
                trace('vm version: '+System.vmVersion);
                setInterval(increaseMemoryUsage,100);
            }

            protected function increaseMemoryUsage():void{
                try{
                    var vector:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();
                    vector.length = 1024*1024/4;//1MB
                    vectors.push(vector);
                    System.gc();
                    trace(vectors.length*1+'MB');
                    trace('total: '+System.totalMemoryNumber+', private: '+System.privateMemory+', free: '+System.freeMemory);
                    totalMemoryDisplay.text=''+int(System.totalMemoryNumber/(1024*1024))+'MB';
                }catch(e:MemoryError){
                    trace('it catches!');
                    Alert.show('memoryError');
                }catch(e:Error){
                    trace('error'+e.errorID);
                }
            }


            protected function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void{
                trace('it is uncaught!');
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script> 
    <s:Label id="totalMemoryDisplay" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702753/as3-try-catch-out-of-memory

Comment: no, this is not a solution